# Change wordpress Multisite default site from side id 1 to side id 2

Tags: multisite

I have a multsite installation with canonical setup like `site1.domain.com` and `site2.domain.com` etc. How do I change the default root site from site `1` to site `2`?

I tried to change these two values in `wp-config` to `5` instead of `1` and there was no effect:

```
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

Is there a tutorial out to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current site Id defines the primary network id.  You can have more than one network if you use a [multi-network plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20120908131024/http://wpebooks.com/networks/).  Current blog id defines the primary blog within the primary network.  To change the main blog to '2' (if you only have one network) you want your defines like this:

```
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Dashboard » My Sites and change the site in the drop down.

Comment: This option does no exist any longer

Comment: @checklist Just file an [edit] and _fix_ the answer. That's totally ok, you will even receive 2+ upon accepted edited.